# How to ensure that my jQuery .ready runs in the end

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an an MVC 2 web application that uses Master pages.  In the master pages, there are several ready blocks just like the one below scattered throughout the file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   ...
});
```

Likewise, many of my views also have multiple ready blocks scattered throughout.

I have been asked to introduce another ready block into the Master that will run last.

My question is "Is there a way to guarantee that this new ready block will run last?".  My thought was that if I put it at the very bottom of the Master page that would do it but I can't seem to convince myself that this is certain.

Comment: As far as I understand how it works, making sure it is last on the page should be enough.

Comment: Since the web page is "composed" on the server based on the Master and MVC view, can i guarantee that placing the $(document).ready() at the very end of the Master file will do the trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the jQuery's `.add` method that is called to push your `$(document).ready()`'s callback to the list of all callbacks:

```
add = function( args ) {
    var i, length, elem, type, actual;
    for ( i = 0, length = args.length; i < length; i++ ) {
        elem = args[ i ];
        type = jQuery.type( elem );
        if ( type === "array" ) {
            // Inspect recursively
            add( elem );
        } else if ( type === "function" ) {
            // Add if not in unique mode and callback is not in
            if ( !flags.unique || !self.has( elem ) ) {
                list.push( elem );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

source: [jQuery's callback](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/callbacks.js)

So: what it basically does is pushing all the functions inside the `list` array and after the event has been triggered - call them in the same order and if your function has been pushed last - it will be called last.

To push it last you can declare it even in the head after including all other `.js` files
(just make sure that there aren't any other `$(document).ready()` below)

Comment: Since the web page is "composed" on the server based on the Master and MVC view, can i guarantee that placing the $(document).ready() at the very end of the Master file will do the trick?

Comment: @wcm I'm pretty sure you can :)

Comment: I just found $(document).bind("ready", function () { ...   });

This is supposed to run after all normal $(document).ready functions have run.  I did, however, place it at the very end of the Master page, just to make sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick i use. In the Master Page, declare

```
var postReadyEvents = [];
```

Then, in the child pages, when you have a bit of code that needs to run last, do

```
postReadyEvents.push(function() {
    ///your stuff - I usually use this to resize a grid or something.
});
```

Now, in the Master Page $(document).ready(), do

```
for(var i = 0; i < postReadyEvents.length; i++)
{
    postReadyEvents[i]();
}
```

When you have $(document).ready() on both child pages and Master Pages, the child page runs first and the Master Page runs last. This approach gives you the ability to control when a certain block of code runs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do a little trick here.
as I don't know the exact case that should fit your solution, I suggest that you add a delay via

`window.setTimeout(`*a call to your cuntion here*,*delay time in milliseconds*);

I know it's not that elegant, but this is what I thought about, let me know if this helped you, thanks.